# ArrayList Filter Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an arraylist `arrTotalItems` of `class Operation.Operation`.

the class has two properties one is `ID` and `name`.
Now I have other `arraylist arrSelectedItems` which contain ID of `operations`

Now I have to bind two `DataList` to name of `operation`.

First `DataList` will be bind to selected `arraylist`.

Other `DataList` will be bind to `arrTotalItems - arrSelectedItems` that is those operations that are not in arrSelectedItems.

not able to find the logic how to bind both the lists

Comment: If you put the class declaration it will be more vivid than describing them in several lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using version 3.5 or higher of the .NET Framework, [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) allows you to project operations from the ids stored in `arrSelectedItems` with [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx), then use [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) to compute the intersection between `arrTotalItems` and this projection:

```
IEnumerable<Operation> totalOps = arrTotalItems.Cast<Operation>();
yourDataList.DataSource = totalOps.Except(arrSelectedItems.Cast<string>().Select(
    id => totalOps.Where(op => op.ID == id).FirstOrDefault()));
```

Note you first have to apply [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) to your `ArrayLists` in order to obtain instances of `IEnumerable<T>` that can be used with LINQ methods.